# Drawing a triangle with rounded corners in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a simple equilateral triangle with rounded corners in Tikz.
However, I can't get the rounded corners correct.

I have the following MWE which draws the triangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=gray!20] (0,0)--(1,0)--(0.5,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried this to get rounded corners, but it has a very strange result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [rounded corners=10mm,fill=gray!20] (0,0)--(1,0)--(0.5,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to get simple rounded corners for the three corners of the triangle?

P.S. I'm not sure which libraries are needed, so I've left them all for now but I know this is probably not needed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make the radius of the `rounded corners` smaller. Remove `=10mm` and you will see the instant effect. Also, *in your case*, I find no need to load the `xcolor` package  since it is used internally by `tikz`, unless, as noted by Alain Matthes, you use some of its options for naming your colors. You can uncomment it if you like. The libraries are not needed here, too, so I commented them out.

Here is your figure when the `10mm` is dropped.

[image]

And here is one with  scaling (not really necessary, just for demonstration purposes).

```
%\documentclass{article}

\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw [rounded corners,fill=gray!20] (0,0)--(1,0)--(0.5,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I have scaled the figure up to 3 since your figure is too small.

To make a point, see what happens when I scale the figure up by 5 and set `rounded corners=10mm`.

[image]

Comment: That was surprisingly easy... I tried smaller/bigger numbers and negative numbers, but just removing the number I didnt even consider. Also, thanks for the tip about xcolor, that was news to me!

Comment: @Mythio See my edit.

Comment: @Mythio: Setting `rounded corners=2mm` in your original code will work as well (even without scaling).

Comment: @jake Thanks, been playing around a bit with the numbers and I think I got how it works now. Great help both of you

Comment: About `xcolor`. Sometimes it's interesting to use `xcolor` with special options. In this case, you need to load `xcolor` before `Tikz` something like `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}`

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thank you for noting. I never really use that much color in work since the printed output just gets reproduced through risograph so I have never really used the special color names with `xcolor` in my `tikz` drawings. I will edit my explanation.

Comment: If I set `rounded corners=10mm`, does that result in a 10mm radius, or 10mm diameter?

Answer (score 11):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(1,2)
    \pspolygon[linearc=0.1](-1,0)(0,2)(1,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Application:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={1pt 3pt 1pt -1pt}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(1,2)
    \pspolygon[linearc=0.1,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange](-1,0)(0,2)(1,0)
    \rput(0,0.85){\psscalebox{5}{!}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the important part here is the `linearc=0.1` which creates the rounded corners?

Comment: @Mythio: You have good intuition!